# I would like to use one Ethernet Cable to hook up to two devices

Tags: ethernet

Description: I have a Computer hooked up to a Cable Modem>Router with 4 Ethernet slot> and One slot using Ethernet cable going all the way to other side of house through attic, and I would like that one Ethernet cable to hook up to the PS4 and Laptop in the same room. To avoid having to buy another 100ft cable and going through the attic. Is there a way I can use the current Ethernet cable in room to hook up to two devices? If so, what do I need to buy/how to set it up? Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. If your able to link to what item/items I need to buy, that would help too. (Also my internet connection is 100mbps)

Comment: Why downvote a question about a technically perfectly possible, even if problematic, measure?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use an Ethernet switch.

1. Buy a switch (approx. $20 for a Gigabit 5-port one), and some short cables.
2. Switches do not require configuration for this; just power it on and connect all the devices.

(Do not try to manually "split" the attic cable in two – that'll only come back to bite you later.)

Comment: So will I get 100mbps speed if I do this? or will it only give me 10Mbps?
So CableModem>Router>Ethernet to Room>Switch>Two Ethernet Cable-one for ps4, one for laptop? will it be around 100mbps? give or take a few mbps lost

Comment: The only sensible approach. Splitting a cable was a thing to do 30 years ago when switches where expensive and connections were 10 Mb/s at most. Even then it was asking for trouble.

Comment: So using a switch will give m 100mbps on my devices?

Comment: @NeoTheOne420 For your setup you won't even notice that there is a switch in between as long as you buy a Gigabit capable switch and the 100ft cable you mention is at least Cat5 rated (higher number is even better). A 5-port switch gives you 1 port to connect 2 the router and 4 ports to connect devices. Gigabit is 10x faster than 100 mb/s. The speed of the ports on your router is the limiting factor.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-5-Port-Gigabit-Desktop-Switch/dp/B00QR6XFHQ/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1483387862&sr=8-2&keywords=5-Port+Gigabit+Ethernet+Switch+10%2F100%2F1000+Mbps

Will this one do along with 2x https://www.walmart.com/ip/Link-Depot-10-Ethernet-Enhanced-CAT6-Networking-Cable-Black/15074878 

Figure I only need 10feet or 15 feet long since switch will be in a small room with the PS4 and Laptop